# Flutter align IconButton center

Tags: flutter, dart, user-interface, frontend

I try to center all these items but as you can see in the Picture: [image]

the Icon inside the button is really not centered, more strange crooked. Why is it so and what can I do against it.
code:

```
Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: [
          IconButton(   
        alignment: Alignment.center,
              onPressed: () {},
              icon: Icon(
                Icons.circle,
                color:  returnColor(null, date),
                size: 40,
              )),
          Text(...,
            textAlign: TextAlign.center,
          ),
          Text(...),
        ],
      ));

Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                children: dates.map((widget) => Expanded(child: widget)).toList(),
              ),
```

Comment: are you refering to the text/splash factor

Answer (score 0):

Put it in a `Center()` widget:

```
Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: [
          Center(child: IconButton(   
        alignment: Alignment.center,
              onPressed: () {},
              icon: Icon(
                Icons.circle,
                color:  returnColor(null, date),
                size: 40,
              ))),
          Text(...,
            textAlign: TextAlign.center,
          ),
          Text(...),
        ],
      ));

Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                children: dates.map((widget) => Expanded(child: widget)).toList(),
              ),
```

Comment: No still not in center -.-

Comment: try to use a Container() instead of Center() define a size for the container and define: alignment: alignment.center